# Why is the MLE for the variance in the Linear Regression model an Biased estimator?

Tags: linear-regression, variance, mle

everybody!

I understand that the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for variance in general is biased (the average calculated from the sample itself reduces the degree of freedom by 1 e.t.c):

```
MLE <- sum((x - mean(x))^2) / n
```

But in single linear regression, it's assumed that the errors are independent and identically distributed as N(0, sigma^2), then the MLE for sigma^2 becomes

```
s^2 <- sum(error^2) / n
```

Is it still a biased estimator? (According to the textbook, yes; but I don't see why) Can somebody be so kind to explain this to me, please? I feel confused.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ could be a good place to ask

Comment: Thanks! @KevinWang

Answer (score 0):

it is biased because the error is calculated by the sampled data, to make error smaller, logistic regression will make E(error) = 0 (that is y_hat is unbiased), so you still use the sample mean to calculate the error